# Remove other elements in an "either or" type selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Truth be told, I don't really know how to phrase this question. I'm still pretty new to web pages and development and need some help figuring out the issue. I've been trying to find solution, but I don't have a collection of jargon to facilitate efficient queries.

I'm submitting a form and there are some things that are required, and some things I only want to submit in combinations. Take the following

```
<label>First Name<input type="text" size="20" name="f_name"></label>
<label>Last Name<input type="text" size="20" name="f_name"></label>
<dl>
 <dt>Enter one of the following combinations</dt>
 <dd>
  <label>Age<input type="text" size="10" name="age"></label>
  <label>Sex<input type="text" size="10" name="sex"></label>
  <label>Address<input type="text" size="40" name="location"></label>
 </dd>
 <dd>
  <label>File Number<input type="text" size="10" name="f_num"></label>
 </dd>
 <dd>
  <label>A<input type="text" size="10" name="A"></label>
  <label>B<input type="text" size="10" name="B"></label>
  <label>C<input type="text" size="10" name="C"></label>
 </dd>
</dl>
```

Is it possible that once one of the input fields is modified to use javascript to remove the other dd combinations?

Comment: So if I modify one of the inputs inside the first `dd`, then you want to disable/remove the inputs inside the second and third `dd`s?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: @JackBashford that is correct. I just don't really know how to begin solving this problem; so, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how, using jQuery:

First add `class` to the element groups. Here I've just added a class called `dd`, but it could be anything.
HTML:

```
<label>First Name<input type="text" size="20" name="f_name"></label>
<label>Last Name<input type="text" size="20" name="f_name"></label>
<dl id="dl">
 <dt>Enter one of the following combinations</dt>
 <dd class="dd">
  <label>Age<input type="text" size="10" name="age"></label>
  <label>Sex<input type="text" size="10" name="sex"></label>
  <label>Address<input type="text" size="40" name="location"></label>
 </dd>
 <dd class="dd">
  <label>File Number<input type="text" size="10" name="f_num"></label>
 </dd>
 <dd class="dd">
  <label>A<input type="text" size="10" name="A"></label>
  <label>B<input type="text" size="10" name="B"></label>
  <label>C<input type="text" size="10" name="C"></label>
 </dd>
</dl>
```

Then we use jQuery to find those elements using the class selector, pull out the inputs and place an event listener for keyup events in the inputs. When one is received, hide all the groups and then just show the current group on which the event was triggered.

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.dd').find('input').keyup(function (ev, val) {
    $('.dd').hide()
    $(ev.target).closest('.dd').show()
  })
})
```

You'll need to research how to get started with jQuery in order to include it in your HTML page.

Comment: The classes aren't necessary. jQuery (and `querySelectorAll`) work fine with type selectors: `$('dd')` Or to limit the selected elements to those inside `#dl`: `$('#dl dd')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleClass()` with a boolean to force the class to (not) be there in the logical case you need it.

```js
// find an input event on all the dds, to get the events that bubble up
var $dds = $('dd').on('input', function(e){
  // the other elements should be disabled if this element has a value
  var hideOtherDDs = e.target.value.trim();
  
  // toggle the hidden state of the other dds, but only if they should be hidden
  $dds.not(this).toggleClass('hidden', !!hideOtherDDs);
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>First Name<input type="text" size="20" name="f_name"></label>
<label>Last Name<input type="text" size="20" name="f_name"></label>
<dl>
 <dt>Enter one of the following combinations</dt>
 <dd>
  <label>Age<input type="text" size="10" name="age"></label>
  <label>Sex<input type="text" size="10" name="sex"></label>
  <label>Address<input type="text" size="40" name="location"></label>
 </dd>
 <dd>
  <label>File Number<input type="text" size="10" name="f_num"></label>
 </dd>
 <dd>
  <label>A<input type="text" size="10" name="A"></label>
  <label>B<input type="text" size="10" name="B"></label>
  <label>C<input type="text" size="10" name="C"></label>
 </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the help. That is exactly what I needed!